# Json call (jquery) to a WCF restful service always run error function

Tags: jquery, wcf, json, rest, cross-domain

I am trying to call my web service (WCF Restful) from a different domain (in the following code they are both in localhost but with different port number which I suppose considered as cross-domain request) using the JavaScript below.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:52032/Service1.svc/std",
            contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",

            processData: false ,    //Same result if i remove this line
            crossDomain : true  , //Same result if i remove this line
            converters: window.String, //Same result if i remove this line
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError});
    }
});

function OnSuccess(data)
{
    alert("Finaly :D");
    JSON.stringify(data);
}

function OnError(request, status, error)
{
    alert("Error: "+request.statusText + JSON.stringify(request)+  " | " +JSON.stringify(status) +" | " +JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

My web service is pretty simple.  `getStudents()` returns a JSON string.  I used `JavaScriptSerializer` to parse my student object to JSON.

```
namespace MyFirstWcfTestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "AddParameter")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/std", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        String getStudents();

    }  
}
```

I always get the following error from `OnError` function, and when I look at the response in Chrome development/debug mode I can see my JSON text.

> Error:
>   success{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}|"ParserError"|
>   "jQuery1706816276672761887_1322704382563 was not called"

My returned json text looks like this :

> "[{\"StudentID\":256,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Ali\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Smith\"},{\"StudentID\":306,\"StudentFirstName\":\"John\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Menz\"},{\"StudentID\":314,\"StudentFirstName\":\"George\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Ray\"},{\"StudentID\":316,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Fred\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Patric\"},{\"StudentID\":603,\"StudentFirstName\":\"George\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Foster\"},{\"StudentID\":604,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Bobbie\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Kolman\"},{\"StudentID\":765,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Jim\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Khas\"},{\"StudentID\":987,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Harry\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Poter\"},{\"StudentID\":988,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Con\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Mench\"},{\"StudentID\":1001,\"StudentFirstName\":\"Jim\",\"StudentSurname\":\"Colon\"}]"

Would you please help me to find a solution for this problem. I have already changed my web service from a SOAP to this restful one.

**EDIT** 
I managed to get my jsonp message wraped in an method (myCallback as follow

> myCallback([{"StudentID":256,"StudentFirstName":"Rachel","StudentSurname":"Smith"},{"StudentID":306,"StudentFirstName":"Ali","StudentSurname":"Flemming"},{"StudentID":314,"StudentFirstName":"George","StudentSurname":"Ray"},{"StudentID":316,"StudentFirstName":"Fred","StudentSurname":"Patric"},{"StudentID":603,"StudentFirstName":"George","StudentSurname":"Foster"},{"StudentID":604,"StudentFirstName":"Bobbie","StudentSurname":"Kolman"},{"StudentID":765,"StudentFirstName":"Jim","StudentSurname":"Khas"},{"StudentID":987,"StudentFirstName":"Harry","StudentSurname":"Poter"},{"StudentID":988,"StudentFirstName":"Con","StudentSurname":"Mench"},{"StudentID":1001,"StudentFirstName":"Jim","StudentSurname":"colon"}]);

And I also change my Ajax call as follow

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "http://localhost:52032/Service1.svc/getStd?callback=myCallback",  //or callback=?
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        //converters: jQuery.parseJSON,
                        contentType: 'application/javascript',
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        error: OnError

                    });
```

But I still get the same error. I'm straggling for 3 weeks for such a simple task :(

Comment: if getString() returns a json formatted string, i think there is no need to specify the ResponsFormat

Comment: also try to check if automaticFormatSelectionEnabled from config is false: <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" 
    automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" 
    defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json" />

Comment: when I remove response format I get the response as a Xml response with a string tag including my json text

Answer (score 0):

Try changing getStudents() to return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) and accessing the returned list through a jQuery each using data[iterator].StudentID, data[iterator].StudentFirstName, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes:

```
namespace MyFirstWcfTestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "AddParameter")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/std", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<StudentDTO>getStudents();

    }  

    class StudentDTO
    {
       public int StudentID;
       public string StudentFirstName;
       public string StudentSurname;
    }
}
```

On the client-side:

```
function OnSuccess(data)
{
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        var fn = data[i].StudentFirstName;
        var sn = data[i].StudentSurName;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Jerjer
I still get that parsererror I mentioned in the question. do you have any idea why it calls the OnError Function while the response is successfully received??

"Error: success{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}|"ParserError"| "jQuery1706816276672761887_1322704382563 was not called" "

Comment: im puzzled, can try another jquery version?

Comment: I have tried different jQuery versions as you suggested and I get the same error.
I assume my json response is not appropriate. is tehre any way that I can produce jsonP instead of json if it's required by jquery.Ajax?(json response is in my initial question body)